# Replace AuthenticationHandler for integration tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a webapp that uses Forms authentication for browser clients and also basic auth for api access to an odata source.

This works in production but now I am struggeling to make this testable.

I use the WebApplicationFactory approach and also managed to implement the test authentication handler as described here

https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#mock-authentication

and my unit tests now work as expected.

However I had to add the `Test`-Scheme to my `Authorize` attribute.

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin", AuthenticationSchemes = "BasicAuthentication,Test")]
    [ODataRoutePrefix("Customers")]
    public class CustomerController : ODataController
    {

        public CustomerController()
        {
        }

        [ODataRoute, EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {

            var result = new List<Customers>();

            return Ok(result);

        }
    }
```

The result is that my tests work but in production I get an exception because the `Test` scheme is missing.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Test'. The registered schemes are: Identity.Application, Identity.External, Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe, Identity.TwoFactorUserId, BasicAuthentication. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("Test",...)?
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.PolicyEvaluator.AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Now I would like to replace my real `BasicAuthenticationHandler` with the `TestAuthHandler`

```
                var basicAuth = services.SingleOrDefault(
                    s => s.ServiceType ==
                        typeof(BasicAuthenticationHandler));

                services.Remove(basicAuth);

                services
                    .AddAuthentication("BasicAuthentication")
                    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>("BasicAuthentication", options =>
                    {

                    });
```

But this fails because the scheme `BasicAuthentication` already exists.

How do I remove a already registered authenticaton scheme from an existing asp.net core webapp? AuthenticationOptions does not have a `RemoveScheme` method.

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Scheme already exists: BasicAuthentication
    Stack Trace:
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationOptions.AddScheme(String name, Action`1 configureBuilder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`2.<AddSchemeHelper>b__0(AuthenticationOptions o)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions`1.Configure(String name, TOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemeProvider..ctor(IOptions`1 options, IDictionary`2 schemes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemeProvider..ctor(IOptions`1 options)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<UseMiddleware>b__0(RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Start(IHost host)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.EnsureServer()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateDefaultClient(DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateDefaultClient(Uri baseAddress, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateClient(WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateClient()
```

Comment: So you add code to add the test scheme right in the `Startup.cs`? Well I don't think that's how it's used. When running the test, looks like you build the config from scratch with `.WithWebHostBuilder(...)` (from the link you shared). There you add the scheme `BasicAuthentication` with the mocked handler. That scheme is the only one consumed by the real code (in controllers, ...). The point of testing is to avoid any modification to the real code as much as possible. So keep the real code as it is, just prepare testing code separately.

Comment: @KingKing Thanks. I posted the question because I wanted to avoid having test code in production (which would have been the easy path). That's why I needed to replace the real basic auth with my test implementation. Anton Toshiks solution did the trick.

Comment: really I don't think you did what should be done with the `.WithWebHostBuilder(...)` - which is in the test code. You should have posted that code as well. I don't think the Microsoft document can lack such a basic scenario like this. I mean you can handle almost every scenarios for the testing code by configuring the web host ***just for the testing code*** with `.WithWebHostBuilder(...)`.

Comment: @KingKing Eventually I do use `WithWebHostBuilder`, the `CustomWebApplicationFactory` has a `ConfigureWebHost` method which is basically the same as `WithWebHostBuilder` and lives in my test project (the purpose is that I can just inject a preconfigured `WebApplicationFactory` into my test fixtures. That's where I put the configuration code (I didn't make it clear in the post).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I was doing something similar, and I ended up replacing the `IAuthenticationSchemeProvider` service which is used by the Authentication middleware.

**Mock Provider**

```cs
    public class MockSchemeProvider : AuthenticationSchemeProvider
    {
        public MockSchemeProvider(IOptions<AuthenticationOptions> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected MockSchemeProvider(
            IOptions<AuthenticationOptions> options,
            IDictionary<string, AuthenticationScheme> schemes
        )
            : base(options, schemes)
        {
        }

        public override Task<AuthenticationScheme> GetSchemeAsync(string name)
        {
            if (name == "Test")
            {
                var scheme = new AuthenticationScheme(
                    "Test",
                    "Test",
                    typeof(MockAuthenticationHandler)
                );
                return Task.FromResult(scheme);
            }

            return base.GetSchemeAsync(name);
        }
    }
```

**Mock Handler**

```cs
    public class MockAuthenticationHandler: AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        public MockAuthenticationHandler(
            IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
            ILoggerFactory logger,
            UrlEncoder encoder,
            ISystemClock clock
        )
            : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
        }

        protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            var claims = new[] {...};
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Test");
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, "Test");

            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
        }
    }
```

Now just register the service with, because it's the last one added it will override the current one.

```cs
services.AddTransient<IAuthenticationSchemeProvider, MockSchemeProvider>();
```

Comment: Thanks, mocking `AuthenticationSchemeProvider` was the right hint.

Comment: Fixed my issue where I ran into "Scheme already exists" issue, when trying to replace the real `AddAuthencation()` with a fake one in test setup code. This solution was more elegant.

Comment: the code from the official integration testing docs doesn't work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1.  It throws the same exception OP got.  The solution above is how I did it as well.