# How do I get Authorization working in ASP.net core integration testing (I'm very close)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication

I've followed [these instructions](https://lukaszcoding.com/integration-testing-in-net-core/) to get Authentication working with ASP.net core integration testing. It's very nearly working. My HttpContext.User is correctly populated with Claims. But my requests to Web API controllers with the `[Authorize]` attribute still fail, unless I specify the scheme: `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Test")]` works. I am careful to specify "Test" as the default scheme when I add it in my `builder.ConfigureTestServices()` method, so why isn't it being accepted as the default?

```
builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
{
    /* Overriding policies and adding Test Scheme defined in TestAuthHandler */
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(new[] { "Test" })
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes("Test")
            .Build();

        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });

    /* Adding Default Authentication schemes
        This is enough to prevent unauthorized client (if you wish to have that kind of tests) */
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Test";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Test";
        options.DefaultScheme = "Test";
        options.DefaultForbidScheme = "Test";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Test";
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = "Test";
        options.DefaultSignOutScheme = "Test";
    })
    /* Here we're adding TestAuthentication Scheme with Handler that will Authenticate our client based on Claims */
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>("Test", options => { });
});
```

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I have the exact same issue - I have to specify the AuthenticationScheme...

Comment: No. The whole thing gives me the shivers. This blockage, plus the discontinuity between test code and the app (debugging a test doesn't attach a debugger to the app), plus the inability to get and manipulate instances of fakes from test code, sent me towards App-as-service-collection testing. (No web server. My tests directly call controller methods). But there too I'm having issues. Good luck, as they say in Dublin.

Comment: Have you seen this? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65777903/replace-authenticationhandler-for-integration-tests

I am having better luck doing this.

Comment: The above actually resolved my issue.  I had to go one step further because some of my custom auth code dips into the the HttpContext.Items dictionary so I have to write some custom middleware to add to this and register it via a IStartupFilter.  Really did go around the houses to get it to work, but it works.